# How to hide some option in condition field in admin?

Tags: magento2, condition

How to `hide some option` in `condition  field`  in `admin`?

I used this blog to create a condition action:

> https://www.mageworx.com/blog/2016/09/magento-2-module-with-conditions-model-fieldset/

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to override this file

> vendor/magento/module-sales-rule/Model/Rule/Condition/Combine.php

in your custom module here

> app/code/Vendor/Rules/Model/Rule/Condition/Combine.php

Content for this file is..

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Rules\Model\Rule\Condition;

class Combine extends \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Combine
{
    protected $_eventManager = null;

    protected $_conditionAddress;

    protected $request;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Rule\Model\Condition\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager,
        \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Address $conditionAddress,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->request = $request;
        parent::__construct($context, $eventManager, $conditionAddress, $data);
        $this->setType(\Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Combine::class);
    }

    public function getNewChildSelectOptions()
    {
        $conditions = parent::getNewChildSelectOptions();
        $routerName = $this->request->getRouteName(); //'vendor_rules';

        if($routerName == 'vendor_rules'){ //Here you can add your router name in condition.
            $removeProductFound = array_search('Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Product\Found', array_column($conditions, 'value'));
            unset($conditions[$removeProductFound]);

            $removeSubselect = array_search('Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Combine', array_column($conditions, 'value'));
            unset($conditions[$removeSubselect]);
        }

        return $conditions;
    }
}
```

Here I've added one condition based on router name you can replace your router name there, and I've unset that both options from that array. So now you will not get that both options only in your custom rule module.

You need to add this line in your `di.xml` file here

> app/code/Vendor/Rules/etc/di.xml

Content for this file is..

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Combine" type="Vendor\Rules\Model\Rule\Condition\Combine" />
</config>
```

Run following command once..

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: its works  what i m expect  thank you  :)

Comment: You're welcome :) @divyasekar

Comment: can you please tell me how ro remove  cart attributes option  from condition field https://prnt.sc/qabr5i

Comment: `$removeAddress = array_search('Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Address', array_column($conditions, 'value'));
            unset($conditions[$removeAddress]);` i  tried like this but nothing was happens

Comment: try to use **unset($conditions[4]);** before return.

Comment: thanks sir, its working fine

Comment: You're welcome :)

Comment: Sorry to disturbing you again, can  you please help me to hide a  cart item attributes in  field https://prnt.sc/qaneea

Comment: can you help me to solve this issue https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/298831/how-to-disable-cart-item-attribute-option-in-condition-rule-field